# Java_Swings/AWT Native Interface give error in 32-bit window OS

Tags: java, swing, awt, native

I follow step as mention in below link and create .dll and java application.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Swings/AWT.
*Every thins work fine in window 7/8 64-bit OS.*

In window7 32-bit OS,  It work after below change in code.

```
public class JavaSideCanvas extends Canvas {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("jawt");
        System.loadLibrary("NativeSideCanvas");
    }

    public native void paint(Graphics g);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        JavaSideCanvas jsc = new JavaSideCanvas();
        frame.add(jsc);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.show();
    }
}
```

But it is not working in window8 32-bit OS.

I found the cause, **jawt.lib** is giving error. If i remove from linker setting of my project,then it works fine

Can any one help me why it is not working in window8 32-OS only?.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Project compiled in jdk-7u55-windows-x86.

Comment: Take care that you select the correct JRE version 32/64 Bit when starting on specific Windows System.

Comment: Using 32 bit JRE 6/7/8 in window8 32-bit OS

Comment: Why do you want to load a Java DLL? Just remove loading "jawt".

Comment: Then it give linker error. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Rovet.Sen\Des
ktop\POC\U\MyCanvas-32.dll: Can't find dependent libraries